# Texas Instruments SN502

Tags: integrated-circuit

My father is Bob Cook, an engineer that worked at TI with Jack Kilby in the 50’s/60’s. He has in his possession an SN 502 IC given to him by Jack Kilby. How rare is this chip?
[image]

Comment: Unless you want to design a circuit using this device you are probably asking in the wrong site.

Comment: Where should I be?

Comment: @CharlieCook Contact [Christies Auction House](https://www.christies.com/) or similar. They can let you know how rare something like this is and if they are even interested in finding a buyer for it. (Or if there is a museum that may be interested.) Some historical info can be found here: [SN502](https://www.computerhistory.org/collections/catalog/102762884). For a little "show and tell" about early ICs, view this [maker faire video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=10&v=VNzkhZBjo5k).

Comment: I would ask an appropriate museum, like this one:  https://www.computerhistory.org/

Comment: Awesome. I have been in contact with the computer history museum, NASA, TI , Microsoft big hitters and others , but wanted to hear from other non-affiliated folks who may be closet collectors and vintage junkies. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: According to this source, https://www.computerhistory.org/collections/catalog/102762884, TI sold a whopping 10 units in 1960. Must be pretty rare...

Comment: Very interesting! There might be some people over at [Retrocomputing.SE](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) that might know something about this.

Comment: Cool gadget.  Nice story.  Interesting question.  Wrong site. Sorry.